# How can I modify ATOM editor's markdown syntax?

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to modify atom.io's markdown syntax specification for some special purpose editing environment (academic texts), but I fail to identify the language file related to Github Markdown among atom.io's packages. It looks like every single syntax, except Markdown, has a corresponding language file, including plain text! Maybe I am looking in the wrong repository. It will be a great if you can point me to the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the https://github.com/atom/language-gfm repo? It's the *GitHub Flavored Markdown* language.

That might be what you're looking for, as you're right, there does not seem to be a dedicated (non-GitHub) Markdown support.

Comment: @Pacerier Do you mean for academic texts? Just use language-pfm (Pandoc Flavored Markdown).